# How do I get fetched data from off-site API from server to Client?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, mapbox-gl-js, next.js13

I'm working on a project that takes weather event data and maps it onto a globe for users to look at.

In one file, I have my fetch function grabbing the data, being ran serverside.
We'll call this file data.tsx

```js
export async function Build_And_Fetch()
{
    var url = BuildUrl();
    console.log("DEBUG FETCH");
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    return response.json();
}
```

Now, we have the mapbox file which we'll call mapbox.tsx
It runs clientside, and so throws a CORS error when trying to import data.tsx.

```js
"use client"
import * as React from "react";
import mapboxgl, { Map } from "mapbox-gl";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";



const MapboxMap = ({jsondata: Object={}}) =>
{
    const [map, setMap] = React.useState<mapboxgl.Map>();

    const mapNode = React.useRef(null);
    mapboxgl.accessToken = "pk.eyJ1IjoiY2djdHNjaWVuY2VjZW50ZXIiLCJhIjoiY2xpM2dld3AzMGJkbTNlcGZ2aHowajZncCJ9.vFc7nroP3Pa0Cg7KAxvZjw"
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        const node = mapNode.current;

        if(typeof window === "undefined" || node === null) return;

        const mapboxMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: node,
            style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v11",
            center: [-72,41],
            zoom:0.6
        });
        setMap(mapboxMap);
        
        
        mapboxMap.on('load',()=>{



            mapboxMap.addSource("test-data",{
            "type":"geojson",
            "data":{
                "type":"Feature",
                "geometry":{
                    "type":"Point",
                    "coordinates":[-71,42]
                },
                "properties" : {}
            }
        })}
        );

        // END
        return ()=>{mapboxMap.remove()};
    },[]);
    

    


    return <div ref={mapNode} style={{width:"100%",height:"100%"}}/>;
}
export default MapboxMap
```

Is there a way for me to allow the mapbox.tsx to call a function that grabs the promise out of data.tsx? Is there another way I should handle passing that information from server to client?

Comment: Remember to use JS conventions. `buildAndFetch`, not `Build_And_Fetch`, `buildURL`, not `BuildUrl`, etc. Only classes use UpperCamelCase in JS, variables/functions use lowerCamelCase. That said: what's the CORS error? (if you get errors, [show those in your post](/help/how-to-ask)) And of course: does that URL even allow unauthenticated third party calls (rather than only working on its own domain, or for third parties with an API token/auth header/etc.).

Comment: For some more specifics, I'm using RSOE-EDIS as my data source. I'll grab the error being thrown, but even still I have other serverside uses for the data being fetched on the server rather than the client. Namely dealing with backups to eliminate network downtime.

The site is going onto a kiosk locally hosted on-site so it will always need something to populate regardless of connectivity to the internet.

Comment: Remember to put those additional details [in your post](/help/how-to-ask), rather than in a comment. Everyone should have all the information after reading your post without needing to go through the comment thread.

Comment: Understood! I didn't include them because I need the data to be requested from the server anyways, so regardless of the error the requirement didn't change. When I'm at a point to grab it, I'll update the question to show the error~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't gotten the scripts to work on my side, I did find the appropriate answer.

API Routes would be the solution. From what I can tell, I should be using my internal API Request from my mapbox map to send a request to my data api. The Data api would then fetch my json data and hand it back to the mapbox.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes

I'm still new to the framework but it appears to be the solution that avoids CORS conflicts of trying to make the request from client, and is recommended by Vercel.